# How to query AWS DynamoDB using multiple Indexes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

**I have an AWS DynamoDb cart table with the following item structure -**

```
{
  "cart_id": "5e4d0f9f-f08c-45ae-986a-f1b5ac7b7c13",
  "user_id": 1234,
  "type": "OTHER",
  "currency": "INR",
  "created_date": 132432423,
  "expiry": 132432425,
  "total_amount": 90000,
  "total_quantity": 2,  
  "items": [
    {
      "amount": 90000,
      "category": "Laptops",
      "name": "Apple MacBook Pro",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

-

```
{
  "cart_id": "12340f9f-f08c-45ae-986a-f1b5ac7b1234",
  "user_id": 1234,
  "type": "SPECIAL",
  "currency": "INR",
  "created_date": 132432423,
  "expiry": 132432425,
  "total_amount": 1000,
  "total_quantity": 2,  
  "items": [
    {
      "amount": 1000,
      "category": "Special",
      "name": "Special Item",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The table will have `cart_id` as Primary key,
`user_id` as an Index or GSI,
`type` as an Index or GSI.

I want to be able to query the cart table,
to find the items which have `user_id = 1234 AND type != "SPECIAL"`.
**I don't know if this means for the query -**

```
--key-condition-expression "user_id = 1234 AND type != 'SPECIAL'"
```

**I understand that an AWS DynamoDb table cannot be queried using multiple indexes at the same time**,
I came across the following question, it has a similar use case and the answer is recommending creating a composite key,
[Querying with multiple local Secondary Index Dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982204/querying-with-multiple-local-secondary-index-dynamodb)

Does it mean that while putting a new item in the table,
I will need to maintain another column like `user_id_type`,
 
with its value as `1234SPECIAL` and create an Index / GSI for `user_id_type` ?

**Sample item structure -**

```
{
  "cart_id": "5e4d0f9f-f08c-45ae-986a-f1b5ac7b7c13",
  "user_id": 1234,
  "type": "OTHER",
  "user_id_type" : "1234OTHER",
  "currency": "INR",
  "created_date": 132432423,
  "expiry": 132432425,
  "total_amount": 90000,
  "total_quantity": 2,  
  "items": [
    {
      "amount": 90000,
      "category": "Laptops",
      "name": "Apple MacBook Pro",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**References -**
1. [Querying with multiple local Secondary Index Dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982204/querying-with-multiple-local-secondary-index-dynamodb)
2. [Is there a way to query multiple hash keys in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663695/is-there-a-way-to-query-multiple-hash-keys-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Maybe you can add into that a delimitter field1_field2 or hash them if either of them is too big in size hashOfField1_hashOfField2

That mean spending some more processing power on your side, however. As DynamoDB does not natively support It.

[Composite key in DynamoDB with more than 2 columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317994/composite-key-in-dynamodb-with-more-than-2-columns)

[Dynamodb: query using more than two attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187924/dynamodb-query-using-more-than-two-attributes)

Additional info on your use case

KeyConditionExpression only allowed for the hash key.
You can put it in the FilterExpression

[Why is there no **not equal** comparison in DynamoDB queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998093/why-is-there-no-not-equal-comparison-in-dynamodb-queries)

Comment: How are others able to query the table using KeyConditionExpression? Will I be able to achieve my use case without a new column and passing the following in the KeyConditionExpression = "user_id = :user_id and type <> 'SPECIAL'", do the attributes in the KeyConditionExpression all need to be Indexes?

Comment: A added some more information on your use case. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that while putting a new item in the table,
> I will need to maintain another column like user_id_type,
> with its value as 1234SPECIAL and create an Index / GSI for user_id_type?

The answer is it depends on ***how many columns*** (dynamodb is schema-less, by a column I mean data field) you need and are you happy with ***2 round trips*** to DB.

**your query:**

```
     user_id = 1234 AND type != "SPECIAL"
```

1- **if you need all information in the cart but you are happy with two round trips:**

- **Solution:** Create a GSI with user_id (HASH) and type (RANGE), then add cart_id (base table Hash key) as projection.
- **Explanation:** so, you need one query on index table to get the cart_id given user_id and type
  `--key-condition-expression "user_id = 1234 AND type != 'SPECIAL'"`
  then you need to use cart_id(s) from the result and make another query to the base table

2- **if you do not need all of cart information**.

- **Solution:** you need to create a GSI and make user_id HASH and type as RANGE and add more columns (columns you need) to projections.
- **Explanation:** projection is additional columns you want to have in your index table. So, add some extra columns, which are more likely to be used as a result of the query, to avoid an extra round trip to the base table
- **Note:** adding too many extra columns can double your costs, as any update on base table results in updates in GSI tables projection fields)

3- **if you want just one round trip and you need all data**

- then you need to manage it by yourself and your suggestion can be applied

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is to create a single index with a sort key. Then you can do this:

```
{
  TableName: "...",
  IndexName: "UserIdAndTypeIndex",
  KeyConditionExpression: "user_id = :user_id AND type != :type",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":user_id": 1234,
    ":type": "SPECIAL"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build GraphQL schema with AWS AppSync from your DynamoDB table and than query it in your app with GraphQL. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/import-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-import-dynamodb)